# Finding generators for a polynomial ideal given some polynomials belonging to it

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, computational-mathematics

Let $k$ be a finite field, $n$ a positive integer and $R := k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables. Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in R$ be polynomials with the following property: $f_i$ has only the variables $x_i,\ldots,x_n$ (so in particular $f_n$ is univariate with variable $x_n$).

Consider the ideal they generate: $I := \langle f_1,\ldots,f_n\rangle$, is it possible to recover the $f_i$'s given some polynomials in $I$ and the respective coefficients w.r.t. the basis?.

More precisely:

> Given $h_1,\ldots,h_n, g_{11},\ldots,g_{1n},g_{21},\ldots,g_{2n},\ldots,g_{n1},\ldots,g_{nn}$ polynomials such that
>   $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccccccc}  g_{11}f_{1} & + & \cdots & + & g_{1n} f_{n} & = & h_1\\ g_{21}f_{1} & + & \cdots & + & g_{2n} f_{n} & = & h_2 \\ \vdots &  & \ddots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots \\ g_{n1}f_{1} & + & \cdots & + & g_{nn} f_{n} & = & h_n \end{array}\right. $$
>   is it possible to find $f_1,\ldots,f_n$?.

It seems to me like a hard computational problem, but I'm actually not sure. I did my best and I couldn't break it.

**NOTE**

This idea comes precisely from what Groebner bases with lexicographic order are. If we compute a lex Groebner basis for $I$, then of course we get $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ (under certain assumptions, they themselves are the reduced lex Groebner basis!).

However, finding Groebner bases is a hard computational problem itself, so this does not count.

*"Hard" in the sense that it is not feasible as $n$ grows. For instance, computing Groebner bases is exponential in $n$.*

**RECENT APPROACH**

What I tried to do is to regard that system as a linear system over the field $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and then perform Gaussian elimination or that sort of things. However, I find it extremely impractical.

Comment: follow the key words "Gröbner's Basis"

Comment: did you see already the implementations mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implementations ?

Comment: I work with F4, particularly. I know their complexity and my problem is based in the *fact* that computing Groebner bases is exponential in $n$.

Comment: You might be amused by this article: https://www.risc.jku.at/Groebner-Bases-Bibliography/gbbib_files/publication_186.pdf

Comment: Anyway when speaking of the complexity of computing Gröbner bases, are you speaking of worst-case or average-case complexity?  Surely for crypto applications average-case is most pertinent?  And is the "average" case known to be exponential in degree?  I am not sure.

Comment: @JohnM It is known, for "generic" systems (regular and semi-regular sequences), which are intuitively "almost all" the sequences. By the way, such a great article you shared! very interesting, I will take a look at it now.